# How to Convert a String (JSON format) to JSONArray

Tags: java, json, arrays

I have a problem when i want to convert one String to JSON Array:

this is String
`arrayPersona = ""[{\"nombre\": \"Luis\", \"apellido\": \"cardozo\", \"edad\": 23}, {\"nombre\": \"Pedro\", \"apellido\": \"Castro\", \"edad\": 25}, {\"nombre\": \"Ana\", \"apellido\": \"Lopez\", \"edad\": 22}]""`

when i try to convert to JSONArray using next code

```
           registros = request.getParameter("jsonArray");
           JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
           Object obj = parser.parse(registros);
           JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) obj;
```

Output: (java.lang.ClassCastException) java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONArray

I think this line `Object obj = parser.parse(registros);` don't convert the String in Object but i don't now why ............

thanks for your Help

Comment: That string will through ``SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL``, fix your ``quotes``.

Comment: Where do you get the String from? Is it on the Java page or do you get it from JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make

```
arrayPersona = ""[{\"nombre\": \"Luis\", \"apellido\": \"cardozo\", \"edad\": 23}, {\"nombre\": \"Pedro\", \"apellido\": \"Castro\", \"edad\": 25}, {\"nombre\": \"Ana\", \"apellido\": \"Lopez\", \"edad\": 22}]""

arrayPersona = "[{\"nombre\": \"Luis\", \"apellido\": \"cardozo\", \"edad\": 23}, {\"nombre\": \"Pedro\", \"apellido\": \"Castro\", \"edad\": 25}, {\"nombre\": \"Ana\", \"apellido\": \"Lopez\", \"edad\": 22}]";
```

Really, I would use single quotes in double quotes instead of escaping everything.

```
arrayPersona = "[{nombre: 'Luis', apellido: 'cardozo', edad: 23}, {nombre: 'Pedro', apellido: 'Castro', edad: 25}, {nombre: 'Ana', apellido: 'Lopez', edad: 22}]";
```